# NodeJS generic-pool how to set request timeout?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to using the generic-pool. I see that there is a `maxWaitingClients` setting, but it doesn't specify for how long a request can stay in the queue before it times out. Is there any way for me to specify such a timeout setting?

EDIT: Added my code for how I'm currently using generic-pool:

```
function createPool() {
    const factory = {
        create: function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const socket = new net.Socket();
                socket.connect({
                    host: sdkAddress,
                    port: sdkPort,
                });
                socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                socket.on('connect', () => {
                    resolve(socket);
                });
                socket.on('error', error => {
                    reject(error);
                });
                socket.on('close', hadError => {
                    console.log(`socket closed: ${hadError}`);
                });
            });
        },
        destroy: function(socket) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                socket.destroy();
                resolve();
            });
        },
        validate: function (socket) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                if (socket.destroyed || !socket.readable || !socket.writable) {
                    return resolve(false);
                } else {
                    return resolve(true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    return genericPool.createPool(factory, {
        max: poolMax,
        min: poolMin,
        maxWaitingClients: poolQueue,
        testOnBorrow: true
    });
}
 
const pool = createPool();

async function processPendingBlocks(ProcessingMap, channelid, configPath) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        let nextBlockNumber = fs.readFileSync(configPath, "utf8");
        let processBlock;
 
        do {
            processBlock = ProcessingMap.get(channelid, nextBlockNumber);
            if (processBlock == undefined) {
                break;
            }
 
            try {
                const sock = await pool.acquire();
                await blockProcessing.processBlockEvent(channelid, processBlock, sock, configPath, folderLog);
                await pool.release(sock);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Failed to process block: ${error}`);
            }
 
            ProcessingMap.remove(channelid, nextBlockNumber);
            fs.writeFileSync(configPath, parseInt(nextBlockNumber, 10) + 1);
            nextBlockNumber = fs.readFileSync(configPath, "utf8");
        } while (true);
 
        processPendingBlocks(ProcessingMap, channelid, configPath);
    }, blockProcessInterval)
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generic-pool)?  I see at least four options related to timeouts.

Comment: @jfriend00 I went through the doc but it seems like none of the timeout options listed are related to how long a request can stay in the queue. Unless I'm misunderstanding the `idleTimeoutMillis` option - does "being in the queue" = "sitting idle in the pool"?

Comment: For further help, you will have to show your code that is using the pool so we can see how you are using it as it is a pretty generic tool that can be used a number of ways.  For example, if you're using `pool.acquire()` to get a shared resource, then you would use `acquireTimeoutMillis` to set a timeout for that operation.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for the reminder. I've added my current code for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `pool.acquire()`, you would use the option `acquireTimeoutMillis` to set a timeout for how long `.acquire()` will wait for an available resource from the pool before timing out.

You would presumably add that option here:

```
return genericPool.createPool(factory, {
    max: poolMax,
    min: poolMin,
    maxWaitingClients: poolQueue,
    testOnBorrow: true,
    acquireTimeoutMillis, 3000            // max time to wait for an available resource
});
```

Comment: @user10931326 - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.